# Result are not equals from CryptoJS and Kotlin/Java encryption

Tags: javascript, java, android, kotlin, cryptojs

I need to replicate the same cryptography of CryptoJS on my Kotlin android application, I already set the same algorithm and transformation for both.

Kotlin code
Extension to encrypt/decrypt: (I not tested decrypt)

```
private val ALGORITHM = "AES"
private val TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding"

fun ByteArray.toEncryptedHash(key: String): String {

    var outputBytes = ByteArray(0)
    try {
        val secretKey = SecretKeySpec(key.toByteArray(), ALGORITHM)
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION)
        val ivParameterSpec = IvParameterSpec("1234567891234567".toByteArray())
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParameterSpec)

        outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(this)

    } catch (ex: IOException) {
        //throw CryptoException("Error encrypting/decrypting file", ex)
    }


    return Base64.encodeToString(outputBytes, 0)
}

fun String.toDecryptedByteArray(key: String): ByteArray {

    var outputBytes = ByteArray(0)

    try {
        val secretKey = SecretKeySpec(key.toByteArray(), ALGORITHM)
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION)
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey)

        val inputByte = Base64.decode(this.toByteArray(), 0)

        outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputByte)

    } catch (ex: IOException) {
        //throw CryptoException("Error encrypting/decrypting file", ex)
    }

    return outputBytes
}
```

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Log.d("ENCRYPT TEST", "DSDASSADAS DAS ADSD".toByteArray().toEncryptedHash("ZGFzZGFzZGZhZ2Y="))

    }
}
```

CryptoJS code (on postman:)

```
const payload = "DSDASSADAS DAS ADSD";

const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
      CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(payload),
      "ZGFzZGFzZGZhZ2Y=",
         {
          keySize: 128,
          iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('1234567891234567'),
          mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
          padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        }
);
console.log(encrypted.toString())
pm.globals.set("userEncrypted", encrypted.toString());
```

Result from Kotlin Android app:
bsOVFANvitVwybiPCcjLe189KuQV5Jb70iLoLQOog8Q=

Result from CryptoJS (postman console):
U2FsdGVkX19tqC2bt+P4KddWhhxQrHyIsRpggPDQX79gI24fg64Cl14rDtuosN44

It's not the same hash, I think CryptoJS do many things, not only cripto with AES.
How to get the same hash on Kotlin? (I don't have permission to change the js application, I need to replicate on Kotlin).

The answer can be on Java, no problem.

Comment: Try to get the value from CryptoJS as in `encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)`.

Comment: I can't modify the JS application, I need to make the Kotlin/Java application do the same hash